# iPod classic not restoring properly

Tags: restore, ipod-classic

I have an iPod classic 120GB, it had a broken harddrive, so I swapped it for a generic SD/CF to ZIF adapter. Now it show the "Connect to iTunes to restore" screen as expected (it previously showed the red X and "go to apple.com/support" message). When plugging it in, both on Windows and macOS, it is properly recognized as an iPod that needs to be restored as expected. However, after the iPod software is downloaded and the restore process has started, it keeps going for a few mins but then seems to freeze, with the iPod still showing "Do not disconnect".
On macOS I when checking the logs I see 2 relevant logs:
From iPodUpdater.log:

```
2022-10-20 09:25:07 STATUS ----------------------------------------------------------------
2022-10-20 09:25:07 STATUS Updater started 1.2.5 64 307 12808001 (12.8fc1) SDK:120600 Aug  9 2022
2022-10-20 09:25:07 STATUS Found a shrouded iPod - 110339
2022-10-20 09:25:07 ERROR VVVShouldAllowRestore:316 Returning 7
2022-10-20 09:25:10 STATUS Starting restore bsdName:(null) mountPoint:(null) podName:(null) serialNumber:serialredacted devName:disk4 state:0 updaterID:33 curVers:2.0 diskFormat:??? service:110339
2022-10-20 09:25:10 STATUS Updating to 0.0
2022-10-20 09:25:10 ERROR -[ShroudedPod updateFirmware:andFormat:]:262 Skipping update since changing shrouded size from 67108864 to 201326592
2022-10-20 09:25:10 ERROR -[ShroudedPod updateFirmware:andFormat:]:337 An Error occurred
2022-10-20 09:25:10 ERROR RestoreUpdatePod:457 Caught exception GENERAL_ERROR {
    "Error Number" = 34;
}
2022-10-20 09:25:10 ERROR RestoreUpdatePod:486 Returning 34
2022-10-20 09:25:12 STATUS Removed pod: bsdName:(null) mountPoint:(null) podName:(null) serialNumber:serialredacted devName:disk4 state:0 updaterID:33 curVers:2.0 diskFormat:??? service:110339
2022-10-20 09:33:18 STATUS Found a shrouded iPod - 21599
2022-10-20 09:33:18 ERROR VVVShouldAllowRestore:316 Returning 7
2022-10-20 09:33:20 STATUS Starting restore bsdName:(null) mountPoint:(null) podName:(null) serialNumber:serialredacted devName:disk4 state:0 updaterID:33 curVers:2.0 diskFormat:??? service:21599
2022-10-20 09:33:20 STATUS Updating to 0.0
2022-10-20 09:33:22 STATUS wrote Firmware: 4718592 complete: 5.045771% (5.045771%)
2022-10-20 09:33:23 STATUS wrote Firmware: 9371648 complete: 10.021462% (10.021462%)
2022-10-20 09:33:23 STATUS wrote Firmware: 14090240 complete: 15.067233% (15.067233%)
2022-10-20 09:33:24 STATUS wrote Firmware: 18743296 complete: 20.042925% (20.042925%)
2022-10-20 09:33:24 STATUS wrote Firmware: 23396352 complete: 25.018614% (25.018614%)
2022-10-20 09:33:25 STATUS wrote Firmware: 28114944 complete: 30.064386% (30.064386%)
2022-10-20 09:33:26 STATUS wrote Firmware: 32768000 complete: 35.040077% (35.040077%)
2022-10-20 09:33:26 STATUS wrote Firmware: 37421056 complete: 40.015770% (40.015770%)
2022-10-20 09:33:27 STATUS wrote Firmware: 42139648 complete: 45.061539% (45.061539%)
2022-10-20 09:33:27 STATUS wrote Firmware: 46792704 complete: 50.037228% (50.037228%)
2022-10-20 09:33:28 STATUS wrote Firmware: 51445760 complete: 55.012924% (55.012924%)
2022-10-20 09:33:28 STATUS wrote Firmware: 56164352 complete: 60.058697% (60.058697%)
2022-10-20 09:33:29 STATUS wrote Firmware: 60817408 complete: 65.034386% (65.034386%)
2022-10-20 09:33:29 STATUS wrote Firmware: 65470464 complete: 70.010071% (70.010071%)
2022-10-20 09:33:30 STATUS wrote Firmware: 70189056 complete: 75.055847% (75.055847%)
2022-10-20 09:33:31 STATUS wrote Firmware: 74842112 complete: 80.031540% (80.031540%)
2022-10-20 09:33:31 STATUS wrote Firmware: 79495168 complete: 85.007225% (85.007225%)
2022-10-20 09:33:32 STATUS wrote Firmware: 84213760 complete: 90.053001% (90.053001%)
2022-10-20 09:33:32 STATUS wrote Firmware: 88866816 complete: 95.028687% (95.028687%)
2022-10-20 09:33:33 STATUS wrote Firmware: 93515776 complete: 100.000000% (100.000000%)
2022-10-20 09:33:33 STATUS Starting format
2022-10-20 09:33:34 STATUS BackEnd: clear 262144 bytes to device /dev/rdisk4 at 0
2022-10-20 09:33:34 STATUS BackEnd: write 512 bytes to device /dev/rdisk4 at 4096
2022-10-20 09:33:34 STATUS BackEnd: write 512 bytes to device /dev/rdisk4 at 8192
2022-10-20 09:33:34 STATUS BackEnd: write 512 bytes to device /dev/rdisk4 at 12288
2022-10-20 09:33:34 STATUS BackEnd: write 512 bytes to device /dev/rdisk4 at 0
2022-10-20 09:33:34 STATUS Formatting HFS
2022-10-20 09:33:34 STATUS BackEnd: format slice /dev/rdisk4s2 as HFS
2022-10-20 09:33:43 STATUS BackEnd: check slice /dev/rdisk4s2
```

And a crash log from AMPDevicesAgent:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               AMPDevicesAgent [26991]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPDevices.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPDevicesAgent
Identifier:            AMPDevicesAgent
Version:               ???
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-10-20 09:33:45.9696 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 12.6 (21G115)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        68619777-2183-AE50-BB2A-88E4028B0CC3

Sleep/Wake UUID:       D260A91F-CCDD-407E-9141-44CB3260507D

Time Awake Since Boot: 30000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       28816 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  AMPDevicesAgent main  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_GUARD (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes:       GUARD_TYPE_MACH_PORT
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000007b07, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace GUARD, Code 2305845208236980999 

Thread 0 Crashed:: AMPDevicesAgent main Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a117685c _kernelrpc_mach_port_extract_member_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a117a0e8 mach_port_extract_member + 36
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1a12a3fe8 CFRunLoopRemoveSource + 280
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1a1247860 __CFSetApplyFunction_block_invoke + 28
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1a1247688 CFBasicHashApply + 148
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1a12475cc CFSetApplyFunction + 328
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1a12a4098 CFRunLoopRemoveSource + 456
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1a12c1fac __CFRunLoopSourceRemoveFromRunLoop + 112
8   CoreFoundation                         0x1a12c1f24 __CFBagApplyFunction_block_invoke + 52
9   CoreFoundation                         0x1a1247688 CFBasicHashApply + 148
10  CoreFoundation                         0x1a12a494c CFBagApplyFunction + 112
11  CoreFoundation                         0x1a12a4880 CFRunLoopSourceInvalidate + 208
12  CoreFoundation                         0x1a1306754 ____CFMachPortChecker_block_invoke + 124
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0fee5f0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0ff01b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0ffe6cc _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0ffe31c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
17  CoreFoundation                         0x1a12c2998 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
18  CoreFoundation                         0x1a127fc08 __CFRunLoopRun + 2532
19  CoreFoundation                         0x1a127ea84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
20  AMPDevicesAgent                        0x10296adf8 0x102818000 + 1388024
21  AMPDevicesAgent                        0x102ba61e4 0x102818000 + 3727844
22  AMPDevicesAgent                        0x102baa880 0x102818000 + 3745920
23  AMPDevicesAgent                        0x10297353c 0x102818000 + 1422652
24  AMPDevicesAgent                        0x102c7cad8 0x102818000 + 4606680
25  AMPDevicesAgent                        0x1029bed00 0x102818000 + 1731840
26  AMPDevicesAgent                        0x1029bfb8c 0x102818000 + 1735564
27  AMPDevicesAgent                        0x1029c06bc 0x102818000 + 1738428
28  AMPDevicesAgent                        0x1029c081c 0x102818000 + 1738780
29  CoreFoundation                         0x1a1280f94 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
30  CoreFoundation                         0x1a1280ee0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
31  CoreFoundation                         0x1a1280c44 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 368
32  CoreFoundation                         0x1a127f560 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
33  CoreFoundation                         0x1a127ea84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
34  Foundation                             0x1a21640c0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236
35  Foundation                             0x1a21f4464 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
36  AMPDevicesAgent                        0x102d4290c 0x102818000 + 5417228
37  AMPDevicesAgent                        0x102a68630 0x102818000 + 2426416
38  dyld                                   0x10325108c start + 520

Thread 1:: CFRunLoopThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a11768b0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a1176d20 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1a1281210 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1a127f6c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1a127ea84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1a130bc68 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   AMPDevicesAgent                        0x1029f80f0 0x102818000 + 1966320
7   AMPDevicesAgent                        0x1029f93e4 0x102818000 + 1971172
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11b426c _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11af08c thread_start + 8

Thread 2::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a11768b0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a1176d20 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1a1281210 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1a127f6c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1a127ea84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1a130bc68 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   MobileDevice                           0x103fa6564 __thr_AMRegisterForCallbacks + 648
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a0ff01b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a1001a04 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 680
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a1002104 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11b0324 _pthread_wqthread + 228
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11af080 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a1181598 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                         0x1a12ab808 __CFSocketManager + 644
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11b426c _pthread_start + 148
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11af08c thread_start + 8

Thread 4:: CoreAudioNotificationThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a11768b0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a1176d20 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1a1281210 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1a127f6c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1a127ea84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1a130bc68 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   AMPDevicesAgent                        0x102c59348 0x102818000 + 4461384
7   AMPDevicesAgent                        0x1029f93e4 0x102818000 + 1971172
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11b426c _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11af08c thread_start + 8

Thread 5:: AMCP Logging Spool
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a11768ec semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   caulk                                  0x1a9c29a2c caulk::mach::semaphore::wait_or_error() + 28
2   caulk                                  0x1a9c0d7ac caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::run() + 56
3   caulk                                  0x1a9c0d3cc void* caulk::thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<caulk::thread::attributes, void (caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::*)(), std::__1::tuple<caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread*> > >(void*) + 96
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11b426c _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11af08c thread_start + 8

Thread 6:: AFCVolumeNotificationThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a11768b0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a1176d20 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1a1281210 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1a127f6c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1a127ea84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1a130bc68 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   AMPDevicesAgent                        0x1029f80f0 0x102818000 + 1966320
7   AMPDevicesAgent                        0x1029f93e4 0x102818000 + 1971172
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11b426c _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11af08c thread_start + 8

Thread 7:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a11768b0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a1176d20 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1a1281210 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1a127f6c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1a127ea84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CFNetwork                              0x1a6076638 0x1a5e0b000 + 2537016
6   Foundation                             0x1a215c5cc __NSThread__start__ + 808
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11b426c _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11af08c thread_start + 8

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11af078 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11af078 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11af078 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1a117a06c __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1a1082fc8 nanosleep + 220
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1a108db78 sleep + 52
3   iPodUpdater                            0x21b9ccd18 +[PUDevice quitBackEnd] + 236
4   iPodUpdater                            0x21b9e31d0 -[ShroudedPod partitionAndFormat] + 1476
5   iPodUpdater                            0x21b9e1fa0 -[ShroudedPod updateFirmware:andFormat:] + 2216
6   iPodUpdater                            0x21b997d5c RestoreUpdatePod(PodUpdaterController*, Pod*, bool) + 476
7   iPodUpdater                            0x21b998040 VVVRestorePod + 84
8   AMPDevicesAgent                        0x102ba70b4 0x102818000 + 3731636
9   AMPDevicesAgent                        0x1029f93e4 0x102818000 + 1971172
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11b426c _pthread_start + 148
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1a11af08c thread_start + 8


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000000000000f   x1: 0x0000000000007b07   x2: 0x0000000000001803   x3: 0x000000016d5e52f8
    x4: 0x0000000000000020   x5: 0x000000011ce34510   x6: 0x0000000000000002   x7: 0x000000011cf0d410
    x8: 0x00000001fa111aec   x9: 0x0000000000000017  x10: 0x0000000000000005  x11: 0x0000000000000006
   x12: 0x00000001a1584dd8  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000002  x15: 0x00000001a15fdee5
   x16: 0xffffffffffffffe9  x17: 0x00000001fa91be98  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000001803
   x20: 0x0000000000007b07  x21: 0x0000000000000203  x22: 0x00000001fa84cb38  x23: 0x000000011cf0d410
   x24: 0x000000011cf0d420  x25: 0x0000000000007b07  x26: 0x0000000104808180  x27: 0x000000000000000f
   x28: 0x0000000002ffffff   fp: 0x000000016d5e5180   lr: 0x00000001a117a0e8
    sp: 0x000000016d5e5160   pc: 0x00000001a117685c cpsr: 0x20001000
   far: 0x000000011ce3edc8  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x1a1175000 -        0x1a11acfff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <a9d87740-9c1d-3468-bf60-720a8d713cba> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x1a11fc000 -        0x1a1742fff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <fc3c193d-0cdb-3569-9f0e-bd2507ca1dbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
       0x1a0fec000 -        0x1a1032fff libdispatch.dylib (*) <b3c7a004-1069-3171-b630-2c386a8b399c> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x102818000 -        0x10300ffff AMPDevicesAgent (*) <95fcc919-13ae-3b45-ab2f-64878c0b1831> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPDevices.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPDevicesAgent
       0x1a2100000 -        0x1a24f1fff com.apple.Foundation (6.9) <8bbf8f9b-0034-34f0-a2c5-13c31941632d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
       0x10324c000 -        0x1032abfff dyld (*) <38ee9fe9-b66d-3066-8c5c-6ddf0d6944c6> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x1a11ad000 -        0x1a11b9fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <63c4eef9-69a5-38b1-996e-8d31b66a051d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x103fa0000 -        0x104257fff com.apple.mobiledevice (1497.1.14.100.1) <cf0a8e9c-8fbd-3bce-9a05-1d93663d5467> /Library/Apple/*/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
       0x1a9c0b000 -        0x1a9c31fff com.apple.audio.caulk (1.0) <fbaaa1ec-abbe-3c0d-a491-0dc66ee9d8ce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/caulk.framework/Versions/A/caulk
       0x1a5e0b000 -        0x1a62bffff com.apple.CFNetwork (1335.0.3) <ba0ade10-aa7e-3168-a6c6-817b01849dd8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
       0x1a1074000 -        0x1a10f5fff libsystem_c.dylib (*) <b25d2080-bb9e-38d6-8236-9cef4b2f11a3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
       0x21b994000 -        0x21ba03fff com.apple.iTunes.iPodUpdater (307) <18663a6f-0535-3676-bad2-894cd9b7c9d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iPodUpdater.framework/Versions/A/iPodUpdater

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.1G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.1G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=293.7M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=293.7M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
Dispatch continuations            64.0M        1 
Foundation                         112K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 
MALLOC                           109.2M       60 
MALLOC guard page                  192K       10 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         104.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
SQLite page cache                  192K        3 
STACK GUARD                       56.2M       12 
Stack                             13.8M       12 
VM_ALLOCATE                        160K        4 
__AUTH                            2850K      362 
__AUTH_CONST                      21.8M      568 
__CTF                               756        1 
__DATA                            15.7M      561 
__DATA_CONST                      20.5M      575 
__DATA_DIRTY                      1802K      240 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       580.4M       10 
__OBJC_CONST                      3924K      335 
__OBJC_RO                         83.0M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         3168K        1 
__TEXT                           592.6M      591 
__UNICODE                          592K        1 
dyld private memory               1024K        1 
libnetwork                        1664K       24 
mapped file                       29.6M        8 
shared memory                      880K       14 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.7G     3400 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.6G     3400
```

It then gets stuck as seen here:
[image: Image of iPod restore being stuck]
The disk activity light on my SD/CF -> ZIF Adapter also stops lighting up and the timing coincides with the crash report from above.

I'm running an M1 Macbook for these logs, but I tried restoring the iPod via Finder, via iTunes (running via Retroactive) and on Windows to the same end result.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you format it first? I found this on [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/715216/Correct+disk+formatting+for+replacement+iPod+hard+drive) which I can't test & contains a few variable routes to sucess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have limitted success but wanted to offer a hand if I could.

Error code 34 or Error number 34 I have had mean 2 different things in the past.

1. was resolved by a hard restart of the iPod Classic
2. was a hardware problem only solved by switching the hard drive from the iPod out with another that was water damaged

To hard restart the iPod classic (from the Apple site: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204307)

> Press and hold the Menu and Center (or Select) buttons for 8 seconds,
> or until you see the Apple logo.

Once restarted have it's first operation be to start the restore process again.
If successful great. If not then it may be a hardware problem based on my experience of similar issues.

Source: I've got 2 franken-iPod classics. 1 in my car 1 now retired, but used to be my main non PC jukebox before Spotify.

Comment: So error 34 is specific to the harddrive? Meaning it'd point to the SD/CF or the CF/ZIF adapter being broken..

Comment: I believe so @shniqq yes but I cannot say from an official stand-point if that is what the error code actually refers to. Only that in my experience this has been related ot read write errors on the data drive. Sorry for the extremely late reply. I only just noticed this.
:-)